# 'graph has been closed' after 'ConfiguredGraphFactory.open'

Tags: tinkerpop, janusgraph, gremlin-server

Environment: Janusgraph+hbase+es

I use tinkerpop gremlin console to manage schema and data. I hope to clean the graph (schema + data) first so I drop the graph(`ConfiguredGraphFactory.drop('graph');`) then open the graph(`ConfiguredGraphFactory.open('graph');`). Then I find a strange problem:

If use `:remote connect tinkerpop.server conf/remote.yaml`, accessing 'g' will returns `Graph has been closed`;

If use `:remote connect tinkerpop.server conf/remote.yaml session`, accessing 'g' will be fine.

```
gremlin> :remote connect tinkerpop.server conf/remote.yaml
==>Configured 10.190.148.85:8182
gremlin> g.V().count()
Graph has been closed
Type ':help' or ':h' for help.
Display stack trace? [yN]
gremlin> :remote connect tinkerpop.server conf/remote.yaml session
==>Configured 10.190.148.85:8182-[a58ab702-b857-4484-8631-ea6b43df46ac]
gremlin> g.V().count()
==>0
```

Does anyone know the reason or can give some advice? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

solve this problem by using cmd in https://groups.google.com/g/janusgraph-users/c/-E7VfEG-cd0